# my multiply (*) command does not calculate

Tags: html, css, calc

my asterisk doesn't work,when I do the calc() function and do the multiply tag which is the asterisk the function does not work

I want to solve this problem as soon as possible because I'm learning to program, and i need you help to solve

--mark-size: calc(var(--cell-size) * 0.9);

the sign (*) does not work and does not change anything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to show your code if you have questions about your code. [edit] your question to include the relevant details as text (_not_ as pictures)

Comment: How are you verifying that it does not work? What is the value of `--cell-size`, where do you use `--mark-size`? Only declaring a variable does not have any effect any effect on your page

Comment: @icaroliver Check my edited solution. hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root{
  --cell-size: 12px;
  --mark-size: calc(var(--cell-size) * 2)
}

div{
  font-size: var(--mark-size);
  width:100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>This is my first div tag</div>
```

Try this edited solution and let me know your thoughts